# Oracle Sql Query (XML column)

Tags: xml, oracle

I have XML column like this

```
<c179 m="28">Test Data</c179><c179 m="28" s="2">Test Data 2</c179>
```

I want to extract data ("Test Data" and "Test Date 2") using query in oracle sql developer. (extractvalue or something)

```
SELECT extractValue(columnName,'/row/c179[position()=1]'),
       extractValue(columnName,'/row/c179[position()=2]')
FROM   table_Name
```

Currently I am trying like this and not working.

Comment: Well - do it! I can't see your question, please help me! What did you try so far?

Comment: SELECT extractValue(columnName,'/row/c179[position()=1]'),extractValue(columnName,'/row/c179[position()=2]') from table_Name. I am trying this and not working!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just one XMLTABLE call (don't use extract or extractvalue; these have been deprecated since at least 11gR2 and they can be really slow) like so:

```
with your_table as (select 1 id, xmltype('<row><c179 m="28">Test Data</c179><c179 m="28" s="2">Test Data 2</c179></row>') xml_data from dual union all
                    select 2 id, xmltype('<row><c179 m="30">Row2 data</c179></row>') xml_data from dual union all
                    select 3 id, xmltype('<row><c179 m="19">Row3 data</c179><c179 m="19" s="2">Row3 data2</c179><c179 m="99" s="3">Row3 data3</c179></row>') xml_data from dual)
select yt.id,
       x.*
from   your_table yt
       cross join xmltable('/row'
                           passing yt.xml_data
                           columns c179_1 varchar2(10) path 'c179[1]',
                                   c179_2 varchar2(10) path 'c179[2]') x;

        ID C179_1     C179_2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Test Data  Test Data
         2 Row2 data  
         3 Row3 data  Row3 data2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am not clear about one thing.

You show 3 rows for example if we have 10000 records do I need to write 10000 rows? Can we call with column name? I will be appreciate for your reply.

Comment: I used subquery factoring (aka "the with clause" or "common table expression(s)"/"CTE") to mimic a table containing 3 rows, called "your_table". You would not need to use a subquery to generate the data to be queried in this way, since the data is already in your table.

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate rows after converting data into one column:

```
 with testtable as (select xmltype(
        '<row>'||'<c179 m="28">Test Data</c179><c179 m="28" s="2">Test Data 2</c179>' ||'</row>') xml_file from dual)
        select
               abstcol.c179
        from   testtable t
               cross join xmltable(
                                   '/'
                                   passing t.xml_file 
                                   columns abstract xmltype path 'row'
                                   ) tababs
               cross join xmltable(
                                   'row/c179'
                                   passing tababs.abstract
                                   columns c179 varchar2(200) path '.'
                                   ) abstcol;
```